# Doctrine 2 DQL + getRow as array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have a really simple query:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM UserBundle:User u WHERE u.username = ?1');
$query->setParameter(1, $username);
```

Right now i fetch my result normal as an array:

```
$data = $query->getArrayResult();
$user = $data[0];
```

Is there a way to get only one row as array directly without doing the $data[0] step?

THX for help :)

Comment: I think you can use $query->getSingleScalarResult()

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats) :

> Query#getSingleResult(): Retrieves a single object. If the result contains more than
>   one or no object, an exception is thrown. The pure/mixed distinction does not apply.
>
> Query#getSingleScalarResult(): Retrieves a single scalar value from
>   the result returned by the dbms. If the result contains more than a
>   single scalar value, an exception is thrown. The pure/mixed
>   distinction does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You might use getSingleResult() instead of getArrayResult(). It's documented in this chapter of the doctrine doc: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#executing-a-query